# Wire generating second function with same name in same namespace

Tags: go, dependency-injection

I'm having a look at Go [wire](https://github.com/google/wire). The problem I am having is that `wire` generates code from a template in a file in the same directory which means that there are now two functions with the same signature in the same namespace, which go, of course, does not like.

How should I deal with this? should i write a script which deletes the original file before running `go build` or `go run` ?

Comment: You're probably missing the build constraint as explained in the [Google Wire docs](https://github.com/google/wire/blob/master/_tutorial/README.md).

Answer (score 2):

Just found the solution.

A build constraint (like `//+build wireinject`) needs to be followed by an empty line, otherwise it will be ignored by `go build` and the file will be included in the build.

Comment: Indeed, the empty line requirement comes from go/build (https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/), but it's a shame that the error is delayed and confusing. We've opened https://github.com/google/wire/issues/117 for Wire to track a potential solution